# Classname javascript the same as addClass jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was wondering if `classname` in javascript is the same as `addClass` in jQuery.
I want to change the following function to jQuery:

```
function slidePageFrom(page, from) {
        // Position the page at the starting position of the animation
        page.className = "page " + from;
        // Position the new page and the current page at the ending position of their animation with a transition class indicating the duration of the animation
        page.className ="page transition center";
        currentPage.className = "page transition " + (from === "left" ? "right" : "left");
        currentPage = page;
    }
```

HTML:

```
  <section id="homePage" class="page center" style="background-color: #add55a">
        <h1>Home Page</h1>
        <a href="javascript:slidePageFrom(page1, 'right');">Page 1</a>
    </section>

    <section id="p1" class="page right" style="background-color: #8ca83d">
        <h1>Page 1</h1>
        <a href="javascript:slidePageFrom(page2, 'right');">Back</a>
    </section>
    <section id="p2" class="page right" style="background-color: #8ca83d">
        <h1>Page 2</h1>
        <a href="javascript:slidePageFrom(homePage, 'left');">Back</a>
    </section>
```

Comment: The second statement in that function completely un-does what the first statement did.

Comment: jquery addClass will keep old classes and add new class you can also use removeClass to remove a class

Comment: @Pointy that's what it's meant to do; it's an animation (probs with CSS transitions)

Comment: It's not 100% the same because setting a `.classname` overwrites the current list of class names, while jQuery's `.addClass` just adds to the list, like the native `.classList.add` method. You could use `$(page).attr('class', ... )` to set the class attribute keeping the same lgic, but it looks like a unneccessary overhead.

Comment: @Tyblitz setting and immediately resetting the `.className` will have no visual effect; the browser will not immediately update the page layout, in other words.

Answer (score 2):

The `className` property of a DOM element node is a space-separated list of **all** the classes on that node. If an element has classes "a", "b", and "c", then `.className` will be `"a b c"` (possibly in another order, as order doesn't matter).

By contrast, the jQuery `.addClass()` and `.removeClass()` functions do what they say: add a class (if it's not already there) or remove a class (if it is).  Those operations only affect the classes involved; others are left in place.

So the answer is that the jQuery methods provide you with an abstraction to manipulate the `.className` property, but it's incorrect to say that they're the "same".

Note that in your function, with these first two statements:

```
    page.className = "page " + from;
    // Position the new page and the current page at the ending position of their animation with a transition class indicating the duration of the animation
    page.className ="page transition center";
```

the second assignment to the `.className` property completely overwrites the value placed there by the first statement.  In other words, regardless of the value of `from`, the value of `page.className` after the second statement will **always** be `"page transition center"`. If, on the other hand, the second statement had used the jQuery `.addClass()`:

```
    $(page).addClass("page transition center");
```

then after that whatever class name was in `from` would still be there.